# twitter bootstrap dropdown in navigation not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a problem where I cant make bootstrap dropdown to work, very unsure what the problem is. I have tried it on my mobile and the menu didn't drop down.

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/UgPNR/)**

Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Norges Idrettshøgskole</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Does it work in regular browsers? If so, can you run development tools and see if there are console errors?

Comment: The funny thing is that in the jsfiddle its working, but not in my browser. My index page is linking to the correct javacript file in the js folder.

Comment: Do you have any custom CSS or JS scripts? Are you loading jQuery and bootstrap.js correctly?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Comment: Make sure you load jQuery before bootstrap.js

Comment: Works great [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fm3ES/)

Comment: Workin, Thanks mathias!

Comment: What if you load bootstrap and or jquery from netdna resource?
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, make sure you load jQuery before you load bootstrap.js

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```